# How to use the "\limits{}" command with ANY math symbols?

Tags: math-operators

I know \limits can be used to directly place lines under math symbols, but now I want to realise the following effect:[image]

My solution is to define the integrals as a new math operator "\int\cdots\int", but it doesn't seem to work at all...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In case you use amsmath, does the `\idotsint` do what you want?

Comment: Have you tried `\mathop{\int\cdots\int}\limits...`?

Comment: Thank you all! It turns out simply using \overbrace_{}^{} can solve the problem..... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `\overbrace` with `\mathop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
=\mathop{\overbrace{\idotsint}^{n-1}}\limits_{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2\le1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe with some visual fixes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
=\mathop{\,\,\overbrace{\!\!\idotsint\,}^{n-1}\!}\limits_{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2\le1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]